# Filtering pandas in Python using 'where'

Tags: python, pandas

I have a new question concerning filtering pandas in Python.

My original data frame, DF, looks like this

```
date        currency      1Y    1Y1M    1Y2M    1Y3M    1Y4M
2013-09-25  EUR            0       0       0       0       0
2013-09-26  EUR            0       0       0       0       0
2013-09-27  EUR            0       0       0       0       0
2013-09-28  EUR            0       0       0       0       0
2013-09-29  EUR            0       0       0       0       0
2013-09-25  USD            0       0       0       0       0
2013-09-26  USD            0       -2      -4      -8      -10  
2013-09-27  USD            0       -1      -1      -6      -1   
2013-09-28  USD            0       -3      -6      -2      -6
2013-09-29  USD            0       -5      -1      -6      -7
```

What I would like to do, is to somehow filter this data on 'USD', and change signs to all available data matching the criteria. I want the original data to be changed (so not a copy), i.e. the resulting dataframe (i.e. DF) would be,

```
date        currency      1Y    1Y1M    1Y2M    1Y3M    1Y4M
2013-09-25  EUR            0       0       0       0       0
2013-09-26  EUR            0       0       0       0       0
2013-09-27  EUR            0       0       0       0       0
2013-09-28  EUR            0       0       0       0       0
2013-09-29  EUR            0       0       0       0       0
2013-09-25  USD            0       0       0       0       0
2013-09-26  USD            0       2       4       8       10   
2013-09-27  USD            0       1       1       6       1    
2013-09-28  USD            0       3       6       2       6
2013-09-29  USD            0       5       1       6       7
```

I have tried using the function 'where' as so (with printing to see effect)

```
mask = DF['currency'].str.contains('USD')
print DF.ix[mask,'1Y1M']
DF.where(DF[~mask], -1 * DF,inplace=True)
print data_BBG.ix[mask,'1Y1M']
```

But the print-results show no effect.

Any insights would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['currency']=='USD', '1Y':'1Y4M'] *= -1
```

yields

```
         date currency  1Y  1Y1M  1Y2M  1Y3M  1Y4M
0  2013-09-25      EUR   0     0     0     0     0
1  2013-09-26      EUR   0     0     0     0     0
2  2013-09-27      EUR   0     0     0     0     0
3  2013-09-28      EUR   0     0     0     0     0
4  2013-09-29      EUR   0     0     0     0     0
5  2013-09-25      USD   0     0     0     0     0
6  2013-09-26      USD   0     2     4     8    10
7  2013-09-27      USD   0     1     1     6     1
8  2013-09-28      USD   0     3     6     2     6
9  2013-09-29      USD   0     5     1     6     7
```

Although  `DF['currency'].str.contains('USD')` may be faster than `df['currency']=='USD'`, I would suggest using the latter to guarantee that you only select rows where the currency exactly equals USD. The former might include rows whose currency happens to include the letters `USD`. I'm not sure if that is possible, but why risk it.

Comment: Appreciate the quick answer @unutbu. However, I seem to get conversion error when trying to apply the .loc.
ValueError: ('could not convert string to float: ', u'occurred at index 1Y')

Moreover, as this is just an example, do you think there is a way to apply the "*= -1" to all columns, as '1Y':'1Y4M'?

Comment: Oh yes, `'1Y':'1Y4m'` also works. Can you tell me more about the "conversion error", perhaps supply a runnable example which reproduces the error? Please post the full error message.

Comment: Sorry for being obscure.
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4556, in applymap
    return self.apply(infer)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4416, in apply
    return self._apply_standard(f, axis)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4491, in _apply_standard
    raise e
ValueError: ('could not convert string to float: ', u'occurred at index 1Y')
>>>

Comment: Please post `DF.dtypes`.

Comment: Hi @unutbu, I realized some of my data points are formatted as "165,67" instead of "165.67", which is most likely causing the problem. I'll try to work this issue out, and get back a.s.a.p